# Updating data from GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have a Gridview where I join two tables, bringing in the data to be displayed

table 1 sid, schedule, stime, splace, stourid

table 2 tourid, tourname

Basically they are joined stourid to tourid. That is so I can show the tourname in the grid.

Now I want to edit this GridView, what do I need to do, for instance, if the user edits the tourname, that it'll be saved to the database? I assume an Update statement is need, but how does it link to the GridView?

Whats the best and neatest method?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Create `Store Procedure` to Update both tables and call it in your Update Code...

```
Create Proc UpdateData
@sid int,
@schedule,
@stime,
@splace,
@tourname
as
Begin
declare @tourid int,

select distinct @tourid=tourid from table1 where sid=@sid

begin try
// update tabel1
update tabel2 set tourname=@tourname where tourid =@tourid     
end Try
begin Catch
end Catch
End
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LinqToSQL you can do something like (if there is a FK relation between the tables)

```
DatabaseDataContext data = new DatabaseDataContext();

Table1 row = data.Table1s.Where(t =>t.ID == selectedID);
row.Table2.tourname = newName;

data.SubmitChanges();
```

You would then want to rebind the grid to show the new data.